# How to get results on the significance of alpha and beta coefficients of VECM in R

Tags: r, significance, error-correction

In estimating a vector-error correction model (VECM), I'm looking for a function in R that reports the significance of alpha and beta coefficients in the error-correction term. All I found was [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96645/finding-significance-levels-for-cointegrating-coefficients-in-cajorls), and according to the first answer therein, it seems there was no such function in R back in 2014, 10 years ago. Is it still true? And the solution suggested there doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any tip?